# Why does my react app reset completely (resetting all states to default values, clearing the console, etc)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-hooks

Here's my **App** component -

```js
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import { useState } from "react";
import Project from "./components/Project";
import CreateProject from "./components/CreateProject";
import HomePage from "./components/HomePage";

function App() {
  const [mainArea, setMainArea] = useState(undefined);
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  function handleMainArea() {
    console.log(mainArea)
    return(
      <div id = "main-area">
        {
          mainArea  ?  <Project /> : <CreateProject onSaveProject = {handleSaveProject} onCancel = {handleCancel}/>
        }
      </div>
      );
  }
  function handleSaveProject(projectDetails) {
    console.log('here')
    setProjects((projects) => {
      let tempProjects = [...projects];
      tempProjects.push(projectDetails);
      return tempProjects;
    })
    //setMainArea(undefined)
  }
  function handleCancel() {
    setMainArea(undefined)
  }
  function handleAddProject() {
    setMainArea(false)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar onAddProject={handleAddProject} projects={[...projects]} />
      {mainArea === undefined ? <HomePage /> : handleMainArea()}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's my **CreateProject** component -

```js
import { useRef } from "react"
export default function CreateProject({onSaveProject, onCancel}) {
    const titleRef = useRef();
    const descrRef = useRef();
    const dateRef = useRef();
    function onSubmit() {
        const projectDetails = {};
        projectDetails.title = titleRef.current.value;
        projectDetails.description = descrRef.current.value;
        projectDetails.date = dateRef.current.value;
        onSaveProject(projectDetails);
    }
    return(
        <form id="myform" >
            <div id = "buttonHeader">
                <button id = "cancel" onClick = {onCancel}>
                    Cancel
                </button> 
                <button id = "save" onClick = {onSubmit}>
                    Save
                </button>
            </div>
            <label>
                TITLE
            </label> <br></br>
            <input ref = {titleRef} type = "text" className = "input" id = "titleInput"></input> <br></br>
            <label>
                DESCRIPTION
            </label> <br></br>
            <textarea ref = {descrRef} type = "text" className = "input" id = "descriptionInput"></textarea> <br></br>
            <label>
                DUE DATE
            </label> <br></br>
            <input ref = {dateRef} type = "date" id = "dateInput"></input> <br></br>
            
        </form>
       
    )
}
```

When I click on AddProject button, the handleAddProject() is called, which sets the mainArea to false, and displays the CreateProject component, which is just a form.

Now, when I submit this form, the handleSaveProject function is called, which should update the state of projects and re-renders the page. But I am encountering a weird bug here, where my entire app is resetting, erasing all states, etc.

(This bug is solved if I just uncomment the setMainArea(undefined) in the handleSaveProject function. But I am trying to understand why it occurs in the first place)

Comment: do `<form>`s in react still work like normal html `<form>`s when you submit?

Comment: I am not specifying the type of the form as "submit", I am just handling a button click event.

Comment: how does one specify `the type of the form`? forms submit on button press - of course, I'm talking pure HTML, I have no idea if eract does things to forms - you could try setting the BUTTON as `type="button"` - that's how you'd prevent a button from submitting a form in regular html

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant the button. I didn't set its type as type = "button" . But when I do as you mentioned, IT ACTUALLY WORKS!

But I didn't understand why

Comment: I think I now understood it. When there's no action specified on the button, the browser just refreshes the page, is that it?

Comment: no, it has to do with form submission